# jquery value doesn't match format

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to validate input field and check if value not match time format `06:15`
But where should be `.not` statement?

```
($("#id").val().not.match(/^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/))
```

Comment: `!$("#id").val().match(/^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/)`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.not` in this case.

The `.not` Jquery function need a `Selector`, `Element` or `Array` as parameter, for eg:

```
$( "li" ).not( ":even" );
```

As mentionned by `Arun P Johny` in comments, the best way is to use the logical `NOT` operator : `!` to perform a logical negation on your expression:

```
if(!$("#id").val().match(/^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/)) {
    //not matching with the regExp
}
```